# (M68k) Why is my value not getting passed into D0?

Tags: recursion, assembly, subroutine, motorola, 68000

So I am writing a program and subroutine where this is basically the pseudocode.

```
int findmin(int* vals, int count){
    if(count == 1){
         return vals[0];
          }else{
          int minrest = findmin(vals+1,count-1);
              if (minrest < vals[0]){
              return minrest
              }else{
               return vals[0]
                   }
             }
        }
```

I basically have to put this into m68k assembly code. In the pictures  is what i have so far. I think my logic is correct but for some reason all this does is printout my header and nothing else, I feel like for some reason I am not corectly storing my result into D0 where it should be. Is there a step I am missing or something that I am just completely off on? My prog4.s is my main that calls the subroutine

[My prog4.s is my main that calls the subroutine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvytE.png)
[subroutine recursive function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0GZd.png)

Comment: Please don’t put code in images. Put it directly in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The *main* code calls the subroutine like this:

> ```
>     pea     vals
>     move.w  D1, -(SP)
>     jsr     findmin
>     adda.l  #6, SP
> ```

The *findmin* subroutine makes next recursive call:

> ```
>     move.l  A0, -(SP)
>     move.w  D1, -(SP)
>     jsr     findmin
>     adda.l  #6, SP
> ```

The *findmin* subroutine retrieves its parameters like:

> ```
> findmin:
>     link    A6, #0
>     ...
>     move.w  8(A6), D1
>     move.l  12(A6), A0      <<< Here is the error!
> ```

**But wait**, because of how you placed things on the stack, this is how the stack is laid out:

```
          A6  RTS  D1  A0
lower    ==== ==== == ====    higher
         ^
         SP == A6
```

The above shows that the **word** D1 is at 8(A6) and that the **longword** A0 is at 10(A6). *That's 10 instead of 12.*

Comment: I'm surprised that the compiler doesn't just push everything as a long regardless of its actual size, that would make the pointer arithmetic easier.